# Why am I getting a NoneType?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I've been through it line by line and it all produces expected results up until new_face, when new_face starts producing NoneType's.

```
import numpy, cv2
from PIL import Image

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("..data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml") #absolute path cut down for privacy

def find_faces(image_for_faces):
    image = image_for_faces.resize((1800,3150))
    image_np = numpy.asarray(image)
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_gray) #correct numpy array, prints correct coordinates per face
    face_list = []
    image.show()
    for face in faces:
        print(face)
        box = (face[0], face[1], face[0]+face[2], face[1]+face[3]) #correctly produces numpy coordinates
        copy_image = image.copy()
        cropped = copy_image.crop(box = (box))
        new_face = cropped.thumbnail((128,128))
        face_list.append(new_face)
    return face_list

y = Image.open('famphoto.jpg')
z = y.convert('RGB')
x = find_faces(z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Image.thumbnail()` modifies the `Image` object in place, read more about it in the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html). It mentions that it returns a `None` type.

Image.thumbnail:

> Make this image into a thumbnail. This method modifies the image to
> contain a thumbnail version of itself, no larger than the given size.
> This method calculates an appropriate thumbnail size to preserve the
> aspect of the image, calls the draft() method to configure the file
> reader (where applicable), and finally resizes the image.

Comment: That's it! Thank you